# Inline wrapping of hyperlink text in HTML anchor tag

Tags: html, css, formatting, hyperlink

I'm trying to find a way to allow really long text in an HTML link to wrap while containing the link in a compact rectangle.

Essentially, I want this:

```
                      with a really, really
    Here is some text long link that wraps   and here is some more text.
                      around in a rectangle
```

Instead of:

```
   Here is some text with a really, really long link that wraps
   around in a rectangle and here is some more text.
```

How can I do this?

Comment: How come underline does not show up in my post?  Underline is displayed in the preview when I'm editing it...

Comment: substituted underlines with bolds for now

Comment: Now if only I could do this with content that has no spaces :*(

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can do it like this in Firefox - it doesn't work in IE though :(

```
<p>Here is some text <a href="#">with a really, really long link that wraps</a> around in a rectangle and here is some more text.


<style type="text/css">

a {display: inline-block; max-width: 100px; vertical-align: middle;}

</style>
```

Comment: IE FIX:
*display: inline;
*zoom: 1;

Nailed it! :)

Answer (score 10):

I know this is pretty old, but it was still one of the first search results that came up for me on the subject. I found that using:

```
white-space: pre-wrap;
```

forced the anchor to wrap the text around my width restrictions

Answer (score 1):

You can use `display:inline-block;` css property on your link which will give you exactly the effect you desire (dont forget to set the width :).

display:inline-block is not supported in IE, but lucky for you someone has already done the hard work and come up with a workaround [here](http://blog.hedgerwow.com/2007/11/14/item-list-grid-real-world-practice-with-displayinline-block-across-browsers/).

Answer (score 1):

I wound up having this issue because I was using bootstrap and it was by default setting this as one of it's styles

```
.dropdown-menu > li > a{
    white-space: nowrap;
}
```

Which made kept the "word-break" and "width" css properties from actually solving the problem

So I first had to set that white-space property to "pre-wrap" instead

Answer (score 0):

```
<p>Here is some text <a href="#">with a really, really long link that wraps</a> around in a rectangle and here is some more text.


<style type="text/css">

a {display: inline-block; max-width: 100px; vertical-align: middle;}

</style>
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways:

```
display : inline-block;
display : inline;
white-space: pre-wrap;
white-spa s: nowrap;
```